# Iterate Through Element in List

Tags: python, list, loops, zip, element

I have a dataframe containing city names in which I converted to a list. I need to take each indivudal city name and apply search it up using the search_by_city option in US zipcodes to find the corresponding zip. Below is my code

```
    from uszipcode import SearchEngine
    search =SearchEngine()
    cities= list(data['Nearest City '])
    print(cities)
```

Output:

```
 ['Dallas', 'Falls Church', 'Anniston', 'New Brockton']
```

For example cities[0], gives me the name 'Dallas", and if I apply the following code I get the zipcode of such city.

```
    zipy= search.by_city(cities[0])
```

How do I iterate through the entire list "cities" to get the zip code for each of the city element names within the list?
I know itll be a for loop of some kind but having issue

Comment: try zip_codes = [search.by_city(city) for city in cities]

Comment: Iterating through a list is covered in any tutorial on lists.  Where are you stuck in following the available resources?

Comment: I am getting this error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension),

```
zipy= [search.by_city(city) for city in cities]
print(zipy)
```

**What is does?** Iterate each **city in the cities** list and **pass each city** to your **search.by_city()** method and finally you'll get all of the zip of the cities on your **zipy** as a list of zip codes.

Comment: I am getting the following error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object